# Odoo - Understanding recordsets in the new api

Tags: api, loops, odoo, field

Please look at the following code block:

```
class hr_payslip:
    ...
    @api.multi      # same behavior with or without method decorators
    def do_something(self):
        print "self------------------------------->",self
        for r in self:
            print "r------------------------------->",r
```

As you can see I'm overriding a 'hr.payslip' model and I need to access some field inside this method. The problem is that it doesn't make sense to me what gets printed:

> ```
> self-------------------------------> hr.payslip(hr.payslip(1,),)
> r-------------------------------> hr.payslip(hr.payslip(1,),)
> ```

Why is it the same thing inside and outside of for loop. If it's always a 'recordset', how would one access one record's field.

My lack of understanding is probably connected to this question also:

[Odoo - Cannot loop trough model records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852582/odoo-cannot-loop-trough-model-records/38866916)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on RecordSets always means working on RecordSets. When you loop over one RecordSet you will get RecordSets as looping variable. But you can only access fields directly when the length of a RecordSet is 1 or 0. You can test it fairly easy (more then one payslip in database!):

```py
slips = self.env['hr.payslip'].search([])
# Exception because you cannot access the field directly on multi entries
print slips.id
# Working
print slips.ids
for slip in slips:
    print slip.id
```